# When one of masters is unreachable all other replica sets work too slow in mongodb 2.6.11 and web application throws error 71

Tags: replication, mongodb

When one of masters is unreachable all other replica sets work too slow in mongodb 2.6.11, also I can not list the databases on mongos servers, and that is because of one replica set. How to solve this problem.

Update:

I have found this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7246, do they say "If you have no redundant network connection to remote site, then go to hell"?

Answer (score 0):

Replica sets are individual entities unless you are sharing resources among them like CPU,RAM,Disk... running multiple mongods in a single server.

I believe your case is that on a sharded cluster scatter-gather queries speed is determined by the slowest shard, so when one shard gets slow all scatter-gather queries will turn slow.

Comment: No that is not my case, all my rs members are residing on different machines, although they are virtual machines(on different esxi hosts).

it takes 10+ seconds to get show collections output.

Comment: I have multiple data centers and a star topology. When I loose connection to that data center, slave in the hub location or central if you may, starts to work to slow, and actually all other replica sets also start to "hang" on my Yii(php) application I often see error 71 internal server error, mongos just drops most of the connections. And that is strange because I have no sharding enabled, and I have one database for each rs.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to 3.0.7 and switching to wiredtiger solved this issue.